# How do I remove window from a balance?

Tags: windows, installation

How can I remove the window? I'm trying to replace the balance but first I need to remove the broken one.
I tried to unscrew the pivot bar but it won't move out. I also tried to tilt one side higher and remove it that way but the window still wouldn't come out. Any idea?

[image]

Even closer look to see the balance hole:
[image]

I don't even understand how they added the balance there as I can't see any cut offs in the channel.

After removing the screw from the pivot bar it still gets stack. It seems the end of the bar is wider and it won't move into the pivot's channel.
[image]

Comment: Does the pivot bar move at all when unscrewed?  There seems to be a stop(piece of metal in the hole.  Maybe the window needs to be in a certain position for the pivot bar stop to clear the hole.

Comment: It moves slightly in certain positions but never comes out. It looks like it has a T shape at the end.

Comment: show us the broken part

Comment: @Ruskes, in the first picture you can see the coil rolled down. That's the part broken. Should be pulled up and attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing the picture below, I would think that:

1. Remove the screw (green circle).
2. Using a screwdriver, pick, or other small strong object, pry the bar in the direction of the red arrow.

   1. You might be able to pry in the hole that the screw occupied.
   2. You might be able to pry at the far end of the bar (yellow arrow).

[image: Annotated version of OP's picture showing points addressed in my answer]

Note that you may need an extra pair of hands to safely do this while also not dropping the window out of the opening. *If* the helper can safely stand outside (on a ladder if necessary) and reach in through the window, I'd suggest that - it will give both workers more room to work without running into each other.

Comment: Do I need to fully remove the screw? It's on the second floor but the window is small.

Comment: I would _assume_ the screw has to come all the way out, but you never know, @Grasper. Try removing it 1/4 turn at a time and see if you can get that metal piece to slide in the red arrow direction. If you can, good news, if not, it'll have to come all the way out. If the window is small enough that you can safely hold it and pry the bar out of the way at the same time without risk of dropping the sash, then go for it. I added the precaution because we can't tell how big it is from that picture.

Comment: I removed the screw but the pivot won't go all the way out. See the new pic I added.

Comment: No you do not need to remove the screw entirely.

Comment: TBH, I'm not familiar with this type of mechanism. From the picture, that looked to be the logical approach. I think this is the right track, but that you'll have to continue to fiddle with it to get it to come out. You're the one there who can look, feel, and adjust - You may have to play with it, wiggling, prying, whatever, to get it apart. I'm at the extent of my knowledge at this point.

Comment: @gbronner please write up an answer detailing what to do - it sounds like you've got more knowledge than I do!

Comment: Ok, I was able to get the pivot bar all the way out and it released the window. The trick was to have the window as high as possible and tilted up side down.

Comment: When you replace it:  make sure both slides are level.  To do that, put the window back in the track and on books  Raise the slides and put the pivot shoes in and put the retention screws in.    Now open the window 'upside down' to lock the slides. Connect the balances and pivot the window up and remove the books.

Answer (score 2):

Having done this on giant windows, this my technique:

1. Close window.  Raise window 3 inches above the sill. Put a bunch of books under it.
2. Rotate window 90 degrees.  Preferably inside. You need to get the cam engaged so the slider locks in the track. Rest bottom on pile of books, and make sure to rest top of window on something else (could be something like a board pushed out the window secured to something inside, etc... Goal is to take weight off of the window and make sure it doesn't twist or fall
3. Hit the pivot bars with WD40.
4. Pull window balance string out a bit and have a helper put a vice grip on the string and have helper hold on tight.
5. Hit raised screw with a hammer and move pivot bar out of the balance lock.
6. Verify that the slider is locked in the track before letting go of the vise grip.
7. If not, use a large flat screw driver to lock the slider in. Or have helper slowly  move slider up to top of window.
8. Repeat for other side.

Now you can remove the window.  The goal here is to avoid accidentally releasing the sliders which will then shoot up, explode into plastic shrapnel, and often break the balances themselves.

I would also add that you should go out and buy a bunch of the sliders **before** trying this.  They are relatively cheap and they often break.

Comment: The balance coils are broken on both sides so there isn't any tension.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the window for some other reason other than to replace the balance coils?  You can replace the balances without removing the window, and it is a lot simpler that way.

Comment: Also, the easiest way to get the pivot shoes to slide is to go out and get a longer screw matching the threading of the pivot shoe retention screw and hit that with a hammer.  The pivot shoes are only a few dollars so you could just saw it off if you get frustrated.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did. I got a longer screw and used it to get the bar out. I'm also going to replace the pane since it has some bacteria growth inside.

Answer (score 0):

You need two screwdrivers

Use Philips to remove the screw holding the sliding bar.

Use Flat and reach inside the hole (slot) to pull the slider as far it goes.

Now tilt (lift) one side of the window till the slider comes out.

The balance gets inserted at the top of the frame.

Comment: Your third sentence to use flat screw isn't clear to me. Which hole/slot are you talking about? And which way to pull it. You mean slide it up? I worry that might be too difficult to do it with the screw. I hardly can do it when tilting the whole window sideways.